# Not able to connect to Astra DB using Secure Connect Bundle

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-astra

Configuration of Secure bundle is as follow.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datastax.astra")   
public class DataStaxAstraProperties {

    private File secureConnectBundle;

    public File getSecureConnectBundle() {
        return secureConnectBundle;
    }

    public void setSecureConnectBundle(File secureConnectBundle) {
        this.secureConnectBundle = secureConnectBundle;
    } }
```

The path to secure bundle is configured in application.yaml file as follow :

```
datastax.astra:
    secure-connect-bundle: secure-connect-1.zip
```

Secure bundle zip is present is application classpath and resides in resource folder

Also client id, secret and token are correct.

When trying to connect to Datastax Astra DB facing the following error:
The main error is:

> Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to cloud metadata service. Please make sure your cluster is not parked or terminated

Error Stack is as follow :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-26 12:04:31.348 ERROR 9564 — [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to cloud metadata service. Please make sure your cluster is not parked or terminated
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at course.prags.betterreadsdataloader.BetterreadsApplication.main(BetterreadsApplication.java:44) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to cloud metadata service. Please make sure your cluster is not parked or terminated
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to cloud metadata service. Please make sure your cluster is not parked or terminated
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to cloud metadata service. Please make sure your cluster is not parked or terminated
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.fetchProxyMetadata(CloudConfigFactory.java:234) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createCloudConfig(CloudConfigFactory.java:133) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildDefaultSessionAsync(SessionBuilder.java:876) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildAsync(SessionBuilder.java:817) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraSession(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:298) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:395) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1167) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1061) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1584) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1512) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.fetchProxyMetadata(CloudConfigFactory.java:232) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
... 48 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here are some instructions on how to connect to Astra DB from cqlsh.  Try it with your secure bundle.  I'm curious to see if you get the same message: https://awesome-astra.github.io/docs/pages/data/explore/cqlsh/#c-installation

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information for us to be able to assist you properly but the most common causes of the problem you're facing are:

- app is not able to access the secure bundle
- invalid credentials supplied, i.e. client ID + secret, or token

**[UPDATE]** After reviewing your updated question, the issue isn't to do with the secure bundle as you original stated. The issue is that it appears your database is unreachable and the driver can't connect to it:

```
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to cloud metadata service. Please make sure your cluster is not parked or terminated
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.fetchProxyMetadata(CloudConfigFactory.java:234) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createCloudConfig(CloudConfigFactory.java:133) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildDefaultSessionAsync(SessionBuilder.java:876) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildAsync(SessionBuilder.java:817) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    ...
```

If you are running the app from a local machine such as a personal laptop, there's a good chance that your internet is slow and there's too much latency between your laptop and your Astra DB on the cloud.

You will need to do two things:

1. Verify that your database is active (not hibernating) by connecting to it from the Astra UI [CQL console](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/connect/cql/connect-cqlsh.html). If your DB is hibernating, click on the **Resume Database** button to activate your DB.
2. Increase the driver timeouts in your app with:

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      request:
        timeout: 30s
        connection:
          connect-timeout: 30s
          init-query-timeout: 30s
```

Depending on how slow your internet connection is, you might need to bump up the timeout further to 60 seconds. Cheers!

Comment: I have modified the question with more details, Please review. Thanks!

Comment: DB is in active state. Also, I tried to gradually increase the above mentioned timeout from 30s to 1200s. I still see the same issue. Any suggestion here.